# Parsing XML in a java 1.4 environment

Tags: java, xml, parsing, mobile

I'm developing an application for an old phone which is running java 1.4 and it's not upgradeable. I can't find any library for XML parsign that is compatible with such an old java runtime.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of distribution do you have ? j2me ? j2se 1.4 included jaxp

Comment: @Hectoret did you solve your problem? Will you provide the additional information that was requested?

Comment: You should have no problem using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[`javax.xml.parsers`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html) seems the most obvious solution - it is bundled in the JRE. You have a DOM and a SAX parser.

If the `mobile` tag on your question is supposed to imply j2me, then take a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-parsexml/) and [more importantly here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1B3GGGL_en___BG265&q=j2me+xml+parser&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=).

Comment: Your answer deserves at least my upvote and probably deserves acceptance from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Not even (an older version of) [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/)?

Answer (score 0):

[Dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/) has a nice API and is compatible with Java 1.4.